# How to get a book indexed by Google Scholar: How to upload to Google book search and what makes a book scholarly?

Tags: publications, citations, online-publication, google-scholar

I have seen similar posts to this one, but none of which answer my specific questions. The google scholar help documentation states:

> Documents larger than 5MB, such as books and long dissertations, should be uploaded to Google Book Search; Google Scholar automatically includes scholarly works from Google Book Search.

**What is implied by "uploading to Google Book Search"?**

I see no way to upload to the search.

**How does google scholar determine if one's book is scholarly?**

Criteria for articles include abstracting and bibliographies. Since books do not usually contain abstracts, is the entire criteria for scholarly containing a bibliography? If not, what is it?

(See https://scholar.google.com/scholar/inclusion.html#content)

Comment: It's interesting, when I googled your excerpt from Google Scholar Help it returned this page: https://scholar.google.com/scholar/inclusion.html, but the page does not actually mention this part. It looks as if it was updated recently, maybe even as if somebody removed this part after you posted your question here.

Comment: Hello, that link does not include it. It is included on a separate tab: https://scholar.google.com/scholar/inclusion.html#content

Comment: Based on the first line of this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Books (Google Books was previously called Google Book Search), I presume that documentation is outdated.

Comment: Last I checked Google Book search lacks any criterion for deciding whether a book is fiction, or at least they don't allow ordinary users access to it. You can't restrict a search to works of fiction, nor to non-fiction.

Comment: Presumably publishers should upload to Google Books, rather than authors, since the latter is constrained by contracts and copyright law.

Answer (score 1):

As at the time of writing, the other answers here are incorrect: you certainly can manually add entries, including books, to your Google Scholar profile. That is done directly on your Google Scholar profile page: there is no need to use some other indexing system.

When you are logged in to the Google account that corresponds to your profile, you'll see this "+" icon on your profile, which allows you to add records:

[image: Screenshot of menu for adding content to Google Scholar]

Select "Add article manually", and when you get to this dialog box, select "Book", and enter the appropriate details:

[image: Screenshot of dialog box for manually entering a new Google Scholar publication entry]

Perhaps just as importantly, you can also select records to delete (when Google Scholar's algorithm incorrectly adds someone else's publications to your profile), or you can select records to merge (when Google Scholar picks up slightly different citation details and thinks that a single publication is actually two, very similar, publications).

Comment: Will such entries collect citations and appear in search results, however?

Comment: If the reference details are valid, then yes, citations will generally be tracked, because Scholar will be able to see corresponding entries in other publications' bibliographies. I'm not sure what you mean by "search results" though. They should appear in Google Scholar searches, and possibly in general Google searches too, although the main book publisher page would probably win there.

Comment: Your answer explains how to upload a citation to Google Scholar, rather than _uploading to Google Book Search_ (as per the question).

Comment: @user2768 The OP wants to get the book indexed by Google Scholar, and was led to believe that uploading to Google Book Search was the mechanism to do that. It isn't required, hence my answer. The OP has posted as a classic  XY problem: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem rather than restricted their question to the actual issue.

Comment: @MichaelMacAskill Perhaps explain that in your answer.

Comment: @user2768 You are more than welcome to provide an answer you think would better respond to the question.

Comment: @MichaelMacAskill I don't think another answer is necessary, I'm merely suggesting that you edit yours for completion, especially as your comments already contain the material

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Google Scholar collect documents automatically from multiple academic repositories and there is no way to manually add any content.

[This (apparently updated) Google Scholar help page](https://scholar.google.com/intl/en/scholar/inclusion.html) mentions that you can simply make your pdf available on your university web space and it will be taken care of automatically. Example:

```
www.example.edu/~professor/jpdr2009.pdf
```

In case you don't know how to do that you can ask your IT department.

If this is not convenient, you could enter your publication in your university publication repository. I would assume that any other repository (e.g. [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/)) would also do the trick.

Comment: For regular articles, I agree. My misgiving about this is that the Google Scholar Help page supplies specific instructions for "books" (larger than 5MB), implying in the process that the normal methodology will not work (see the link above).

Answer (score 0):

I think the point is that one does not directly arrange that one's own documents are indexed in Google Scholar and such. Indeed, if that were possible, it would seriously degrade the usefulness of Google Scholar, since there'd be no quality control. So one must hope that someone *else* finds one's work of sufficient merit...

Comment: I agree, which is what my second question was addressing. My first question does not refer to uploading to google scholar, but rather "google book search," which they specifically say you can do in the help documentation in the link provided above.